# Using lightbox2 to display text instead of images

Tags: lightbox2

I am trying to use lightbox2 to display a block of text after clicking a heading element:

something like

```
<a href="something"><h3>name</h3></a>
```

I have used lightbox for images with captions but this time I would like the caption to come up without an associated image after clicking a name on a webpage.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that lightbox2 is made for such a thing, why don't you try http://fancybox.net/ this one works 100%.